# Blueimp gallery - very slow - lazy load possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading, blueimp

We use [Blueimp-gallery-carousel](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) in our website. As far as I know, the gallery is loading all images at once. I need to speed up the website so I want this `carousel` to load images in `lazy` mode.

So when user opens the page, only the first image in carousel is loaded immediately.

Do you know how to make it work? Or another way to speed up the page? More details are below the code.

**CODE**

```
reloadGalleries = function () {
            var galleries = document.getElementsByClassName("nehnutelnostImages");

            for (var i = 0; i < galleries.length; i++) {
                var id = galleries[i].id;
                blueimp.Gallery(
                    galleries[i].getElementsByTagName('a'),
                    {
                        container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel' + id,
                        carousel: true,
                        stretchImages: 'cover',
                        startSlideshow: false,
                        toggleControlsOnSlideClick: false
                    }
                );
            }
        };
```

**MORE DETAILS**

We have a page full of cars. Every card has its gallery (gallery can have up to 100 images).

So if we have for example 10 cards on the page, there can be 9*100 = 900 images which is too much.

The page is slow and we noticed that if we reduce the number of images in gallery, it speeds up the page.